# How to write the Automator/Applescript Service for "Selected Text" Manipulation converted from working Python "text from file" Manipulation code

Tags: python, applescript

So I have a python script that takes the text from a text file and can "tabulate" (put into a table-like form) the lines in that file, writing the final formatted text to another text file;

```
i=0
k=4  #determains columns of "tabular" form

f1 = open("lines-grouped.txt", 'wb')
with open("lines-to-group.txt", 'r') as multilines_filea:
    multilines = multilines_filea.readlines()

for line in multilines:
    line = line.strip()
    if i == k-1:
        i=0
        f1.writelines([bytes(line + '\r\n','UTF-8')])
    else:
        f1.writelines([bytes(line + ' | ','UTF-8')])
        i=i+1

multilines_filea.close()
f1.close()
```

There is one major limitation here I think an Automator Service would resolve and that is that whatever segment of text I want to tabulate, needs to be saved in my "lines-to-group.txt" file.

Ideally I want it to be as simple as;

```
on run(input, parameters)
-- My Python Logic to manipulate "input"
return input
end run
```

where input is the selected text in any application. Then when I run into the following issue (which I've found when copying tables from rich text format into Evernote);

```
Name
Age
Position
Salary
John Doe
21
Test Analyst
$60,000
Joe Dirt
30
Janitor
$30,000
Jane Doe
55
Executive
$150,000
```

I can select it all in the current note/file and just run the Automator Service to get;

```
Name | Age | Position | Salary
John Doe | 21 | Test Analyst | $60,000
Joe Dirt | 30 | Janitor | $30,000
Jane Doe | 55 | Executive | $150,000
```

Which is what my python code gives me now, but I have to put what I want formated into another file then run the script then copy the formatted text from my output file, and it's all too tedious.

So the real question is; How do I get the applescript to handle my "input" the way my python script reads and handles its input?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, how do you want to pass the data: applescript --> python script, python script --> applescript or  applescript --> python script --> applescript?

Comment: Ideally I want it to be as simple as having the input be the selected text from within any application.
Then the Selected Text is sent into the Service (Automator/Applescript) where new Automator/Applescript friendly logic, that was once my python logic (that I know works in its own ways), manipulates and returns the Selected Text.

Comment: Okay, so you want the applescript to do the same thing as the python script basically?

Comment: @turingtested, yes... so assuming **input** in the applescript is equivalent to my python **multilines** list I get "_with iline in **input**_" to replace my main python _for loop_, I think, but then I do not know how to construct in applescript an **output** that I can return that resembles the "_lines-grouped.txt_" from my python script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can do it. First make a oneliner of the Python script, like this (first two lines here are just input for testing):

```
s = 'Name\nAge\nPosition\nSalary\nJohn Doe\n21\nTest Analyst\n$60,000' #partial list
k = '4'
print '\n'.join([' | '.join(s.split('\n')[i:i+int(k)]) for i in range(0,len(s.split('\n')),int(k))])
```

Then you can run the Python code as a shell script inside AppleScript. You use the Python `sys` library to pass in the input values, replace *s* and *k* with `sys.argv[1]` and `sys.argv[2]`. So the final code you put inside Automator/AppleScript would look something like this:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set numberOfColumns to 4
    repeat with selectedText in input
        set pythonScript to "import sys; print '\\n'.join([' | '.join(sys.argv[1].split('\\n')[i:i+int(sys.argv[2])]) for i in range(0,len(sys.argv[1].split('\\n')),int(sys.argv[2]))])"
        set result to do shell script "python -c " & quoted form of pythonScript & space & quoted form of selectedText & space & numberOfColumns
    end repeat
end run
```

Set *Service receives selected 'text' in any application*, tick *Output replaces selected text*, and then it should work, i.e. if you use it in an application where editing is enabled.
Have fun!

Comment: @turningtested, I appreciate this much! It almost works exactly like I expect it to but I’m not getting the newline after _numberOfColumns_, it’s just replacing all newlines with " | "... but it is a great place for me to start looking at. If I get it I’ll update what I did, as I’m sure you’ll update me if you have more to add :)

Comment: I only had to change the First instance of '\\n' to an identifiable **delimiter** and changed the result to a _preresult_ that I could change into a list form as the actual *result*, I’ll post it as an answer too but;
set pythonScript to "import sys; print '|><|'.join(...) for i in range(0,len(...))"
set preresult to do shell script "python -c " & quoted form of pythonScript & space & quoted form of selectedText & space & numberOfColumns end repeat
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"|><|"}
set result to every text item of preresult end run

Answer (score 0):

Most of the final answer comes from [turningtested](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3776782/turingtested) but the initial `\\n` in theirs did not do anything for me (it MAY for others, I don’t know, `\\r` did the same), so I made a clearly identifiable delimiter `|><|` then by changing `result` to `preresult` and by adding;

```
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"|><|"}
    set result to every text item of preresult
```

The script runs exactly as I need it to, tabulating the selected text into `numberOfColumns` columns (item | item | item | ... \newline).

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set numberOfColumns to 3 -- Column Number May add UI to input on demand
    repeat with selectedText in input
        set pythonScript to "import sys; print '|><|'.join([' | '.join(sys.argv[1].split('\\n')[i:i+int(sys.argv[2])]) for i in range(0,len(sys.argv[1].split('\\n')),int(sys.argv[2]))])"
        set preresult to do shell script "python -c" & quoted form of pythonScript & space & quoted form of selectedText & space & numberOfColumns
    end repeat
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"|><|"}
    set result to every text item of preresult
end run
```